# shortcode causes broken paragraph tags

Tags: shortcode, wp-autop

I'm learning how to use short codes but I don't undrestand why WordPress keeps rendering broken paragraph tags.

I created a file called `wp-content/themes/twentytwentythree/templates/single.html` with the following content:

```
<main class="wp-block-group" style="margin-top:var(--wp--preset--spacing--50)">
<!-- wp:shortcode -->
[wl_event_head]
<!-- /wp:shortcode -->
</main>
```

I then made a file called `wp-content/plugins/wl/wl.php` with the following contents:

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: Hello
 * Description: World
 */

function wl_event_head($att) {
  return '<section>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello WP</h1>
  </div>
</section>';
}

add_shortcode('wl_event_head', 'wl_event_head');
```

When I look View Source of FireFox, I see this:

```
<main class="wp-block-group" style="margin-top:var(--wp--preset--spacing--50)">
<section>
<div>
<h1>Hello WP</h1>
</p></div>
</section>

</main>
```

Why is there a closing `p` tag?   I noticed that if I delete some spaces in my return string for `function wl_event_head($att)`, then sometimes maybe the closing `p` tag goes away.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Note: I tried putting this code in my `wp-content/themes/twentytwentythree/functions.php`

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

It did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around my problem by **minifying** my html in my plugin.  So I made a function called `wl_minify_html(String $htmlString)` (which I found some another stack overflow answer somewhere).  So here's what my plugin looks like now:

```
<?php

function wl_minify_html($htmlString) {

    $search = array(
        '/\>(\s)+\</s',     // strip white space between tags
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',     // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',     // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s',         // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
        '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/' // Remove HTML comments
    );

    $replace = array(
        '><',
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1',
        ''
    );

    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $htmlString);

    return $buffer;
}


function wl_event_head($att) {
  return wl_minify_html('<section>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello WP</h1>
  </div>
</section>');
}
```